# Is the shortest path to a curve orthogonal to that curve?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-curves

I'm wondering if the following is true.  In $\mathbb R^2$, let $\gamma(t)$ be a $\mathcal C^1$ curve parametrized over $\mathbb R$ and let
\begin{align}
d(p) &= \min_t\{\mathrm{dist}_\mathrm{eucl}(p,\gamma(t))\}\\
\end{align}

Let $t_0$ be one of the $t$ that solve the minimization of $d(p)$.  Is it true that the segment $[\gamma(t_0),p]$ is orthogonal to $\frac{\mathrm d \gamma}{\mathrm d t}(t_0)$ ?

I'm not necessarily looking for a rigorous proof, but a hint of how to prove this (or a counter example).  Thank you for any help.

Comment: Do you require the domain of $\gamma$ be a compact interval or not?

Comment: I think I would imagine a small circle centered at $p$ which expands until it touches the curve.  The curve will be tangent to the circle and therefore perpendicular to the radius.

Comment: I image the domain of $\gamma$ to be $\mathbb R$ or $\gamma$ to be closed with domain $[0,1]$.

Comment: B. Goddard.  Good intuition.  You should put it as an aswer.

Comment: There is no reason to believe that the minimum exists. Consider $\gamma(t) = (\exp(-t^2), 0)$ and $p = (-1,0)$.

Comment: True.  I am suddenly reminded of Poincaré : "we have seen a mass of bizarre functions which appear to be forced to resemble as little as possible honest functions which serve some purpose".

Comment: @Lærne My comment above is really Lagrange multipliers.  If you want to get away from the "mass of bizarre functions", maybe you want to restrict your curve to be the level curve of a $C^1$ (or $C^2$) function of two variable(?)

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Assume the minimum is realized at an interior point $t_0$ of the parameter interval. Let $h(t) = ||p - \gamma(t)||^2$ and compute $h'(t_0)$, which must be zero.

Answer (score 1):

Without further conditions on $p$, I believe a counter-example is easy to find.
Take $\gamma(t) = (1+t, 1+t)$ parametrized over non-negative times $t$, and $p = (0,0)$. Then the minimisation problem is solved by $t_0 = 0$, but the segment $[\gamma(t_0), p] $, connecting the origin to $(1,1)$ is not orthogonal to $\frac{\mathrm{d}\gamma}{\mathrm{d}t}(t_0)$.

Comment: Would this really be considered a $C^1$ curve?  (Honest question.)

Comment: I don't know, but anyway I didn't mean a curve with boundaries.  I'm updating the question.

Comment: @B. Goddard why don't you think so?

Comment: @magma  I've been in discussions over whether, say, the unit step function is "continuous on $[0,1].$  Some say no because there's a discontinuity at $0$.  Others say yes because it is in the induced topology.